# How function works in python

Tags: python, function

```
def fun1():
    x="Hello"
    print(x)
    def fun2():
        x = "world"
        print(x)
    fun2()
fun1()
```

Which function is called first and why?

Comment: `fun1` will be called first. It's all about indentation in Python.

Comment: The code of the function block only runs when the function is called. If you're new to Python, pythontutor.com might be helpful to visualize how blocks of code are executed and the variable scopes.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `fun1()` is called first as it is at the bottom of your code and has no indentation. Then when running `fun1()`, `fun2()` will be called at the end of `fun1()` as `fun2()` is in `fun1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions will be called as per order of function execution statements
So fun1 will get called first , then  fun2 will get called.
However fun2 will finish before fun1